# Fancytree selectMode 3 not showing initial selection values

Tags: fancytree

I'm impressed with Fancytree's select mode 3 - it's exactly what I need.  However, the checkboxes do not initialize correctly as per the data structure.  This is even demonstrated on the example itself:

http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/#sample-select.html

In the selectMode 3 (hierarchical multi-selection) example, the checkbox with the label "item2: selected on init" is not selected, as it is in the other selectModes.  I've tried going through the APIs to possibly brute force set the checked values based on the input data but can't find a good method to set the selected value based on the node key.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

selectedMode 3 will be made a selection on parent node if children node are selected, it will ignore a parent **selected:true** property.